# Sending emails with CakePHP not works using CakeEmail and also SwiftMailer

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send emails from CakePHP but without success. I'm trying with CakeEmail and this code:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('reynierpm@gmail.com' => __('Recruitment Job App')))
      ->to('reynierpm@gmail.com')
          ->subject(__('Recruitment Status Update'))
          ->send(__('Dear, ReynierPM this is a testing email'));
```

And doesn't work because no emails is send. The file /app/Config/email.php have this configuration:

```
class EmailConfig {
   public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Debug',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'mlrepemi@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret_password',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);  
}
```

I've try also this http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sky_l3ppard/2009/11/07/updated-swiftmailer-4-xx-component-with-attachments-and-plugins but in this case I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'testemailView' not found in /var/www/html/jobapp/app/Controller/Component/swift_mailer.php on line 245

I'm using CakePHP 2.0.6 and SwiftMailer 4.1.5, any help? 
Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: the fatal error seems clear to me.

Comment: wow, you dumb, posting your password on a public site like that

Comment: I miss to hide that but anyway it's a test account so hacker go for it jajajaja

Comment: i did, see the draft folder, so go change the password now.

Comment: Ok, here is the new version with no password http://pastebin.com/6PbEAaK3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are leaving out some important parts to enable email. You should have something like this:

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
```

Then in your email.php config, your default configuration for gmail should looke like this:

```
public $default = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right but what about if I don't want to use SSL and only the basic SMTP with port 25? I give a try changing host to smtp.gmail.com and port to 25 but get this: Connection timed out
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred. and I have direct connection.

Comment: That's because gmail only supports SSL. They do not allow port 25. That is why you  are getting the error.

Comment: You've got the points ;) but one more question how do I know if my PHP supports SSL or what I need in order to work with ssl://smtp.gmail.com??

Comment: SSL defines the connection. It's a protocol. What you are asking is like asking whether or not PHP works with HTML. It will work as long as the other end has it configured to work.